# Hbase RegexStringComparator Filter giving more rows than expected

Tags: regex, hadoop, hbase

I have a FilterList with several RegexStringComparator filters. I have an issue when the regex string is similar to `.*15.0.0`. This will pick up rows such as `xxx15.0` which I am not interested in. I assume this is because `xxx15.0` is effectively acting as `xxx15.0.*` for the matching. Is there any way around this in hbase?

Comment: Can you post examples of what you want to match? Can you post the full line being matched (the one you are not interested in)?

Comment: I'm trying to match certain versions of software. For example, `shockwave:15.0` and `shockwave:15.0.0` could both be rows. However, I am only interested in `shockwave:15.0` so if I use a regex filter with `shockwave.*:15.0` I only want the `shockwave:15.0` row to be part of the Result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like you need to specify how the string is to be terminated.  You don't really provide enough information, so I'll give you your options and you can pick the one that fits your situation.

If the version string appears in another string, such as `shockwave:15.0 installed` or the like, what you really want is to say "match the string `shockwave:15.0` that's NOT followed by a period".  You can do that like this:

```
shockwave:15\.0[^.]
```

If the string appears at the end of a line, you can can just specify the end-of-line anchor:

```
shockwave:15\.0$
```

If it could be either (in the middle of the line or at the end of it), you can combine the two:

```
shockwave:15\.0($|[^.])
```

That should cover all the cases....

Comment: The end-of-line anchor was what I was searching for. I thought I would need something more HBase RowFilter specific but that worked perfectly. Thanks